# How set a time type field programmatically?

Tags: entities, 8, database, plugins

I create a custom content entity type.

I want one field for the event time.

Since there is no time field, but a dataTime_type, I create a plugin for a custom field :

> FieldType : TimeItem.php

```
/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'time' field type.
 *
 * @FieldType(
 *   id = "time",
 *   label = @Translation("Time Field"),
 *   description = @Translation("Permet la creation d'un champ de type time"),
 *   default_widget = "time_widget",
 *   default_formatter = "time_formatter"
 * )
 */

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function schema(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    return array(
        'columns' => array(
            'value' => array(
                'description' => 'The time value.',
                'type' => 'int',
                'length' => 6,
            ),
        ),

    );
  }
```

I try to change type to time (for mysql) but mysql error return me a null for the type.
So I use int for store time in seconde.

> FieldWidget : TimeWIdget.php

```
/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
$value = isset($items[$delta]->value) ? $items[$delta]->value : '';
$element += array(
'#type' => 'time', //HTML5 input
'#default_value' => $value,
'#size' => 4,
'#element_validate' => array(
array($this, 'validate'),
),
);

return $element;
}
```

My entity :

```
 $fields['heure_evenement'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('time')
        ->setLabel(t('test'))
        ->setDescription(t('test'))
        ->setRequired(TRUE)
        ->setDefaultValue('')
        ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
            'label' => 'above',
            'type' => 'string',
            'weight' => 3,
        ))
        ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
            'weight' => 3,
        ))
        ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
        ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

All is working except one thing, the HTML5 input type **time**

Drupal know some input in html5 but not all... type tel, email, number, range, color, date, datetime is ok but not the type time alone.

So I was hoping get it with a custom plugin, but no...

**Edit 1**

The only way I have found is to create 2 select for this type :

```
public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
$value = isset($items[$delta]->value) ? $items[$delta]->value : '';

    //heure
    for($i=0;$i<=24;$i++){
        $hour[]=$i;
    }

    //minutes
    for($i=0;$i<=59;$i++){
        $minutes[]=$i;
    }


$element += array('hour'=>array(
    '#title'=>t('Hour'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options'=>$hour,
    '#default_value' => $value,
    '#element_validate' => array(
    array($this, 'validate'),
    ),
)
);

    $element += array('minutes'=>array(
        '#title'=>t('Minutes'),
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options'=>$minutes,
        '#default_value' => $value,
        '#element_validate' => array(
            array($this, 'validate'),
        ),
    )
    );


return $element;
}
```

Any idea about this?

Comment: I need a field type like this, can you share your code in github or in other place?

Comment: You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/time_field module.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The form element property `#type` refers to an element type, not a HTML element. It is okay to define your own element types (or theme types), and you can provide your own markup for it. This can be done by implementing a [RenderElement](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Element!RenderElement.php/class/RenderElement/8.2.x) plugin.

Update:

You can also use the `datetime` render element and disable the date portion.

`$element['#date_date_element'] = 'none';`

Update 2:

The [comment form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!comment!src!CommentForm.php/function/CommentForm%3A%3Aform/8.2.x) has an example of a render array that uses the `datetime` type. So given that as a guideline,

```
  $form['time_without_date'] = array(
    '#type' => 'datetime',
    '#title' => $this->t('Time without date'),
    // HTML 5 time element format can be H:i
    '#default_value' => DrupalDateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '1970-01-01 20:00', 'UTC'),
    '#size' => 20,
    '#date_date_element' => 'none',
    // This sets html 5 time element use explicitly, probably not necessary.
    '#date_time_element' => 'time',
  );
```

Comment: I also remembered something about the datetime element. You should be able to set `none` for the date portion and get back only the time portion.

Comment: @mradcliffe Could you provide detailed instructions for this newbie? If I'm able to get it working, I would not hesitate to give you the bounty! Thanks!

Comment: Is there something particular that you are stuck on? It's probably hard to post code in a comment, but I would make sure that in your form array the appropriate element properties (keys with '#') are set. I'll update the answer with some examples from api.drupal.org in a bit.

Comment: That may be a limitation of the browser you are testing in.

Comment: @mradcliffe Flushed the cache... The changes applied in G Chrome, but the arrows and the dashes disappear. Is this my fault or the expect result of doing a different format?

Comment: @ChrisHappy If you have the module or the code that create the field type can you share the code?

Comment: He created another question here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/227029/create-a-time-range-field, as his question was more specific to field widget rather than form API elements.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer Yes, I have shared the code [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/227029/create-a-time-range-field). I'll consider transforming it to Github. Hope it helps!