# Create a time range field

Tags: 8, datetime

I'm trying to make my own time range field widget, but I can't seem to make it work. I

- saw this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206583/)
- concluded that my skill level isn't high enough to implement
- offered bounty
- did not receive more details regarding implementing
- researched for half a day
- can't figure out how to implement a time range field

My current structure of my custom module time_range is this:

```
time_range
  src
    Plugin
      Field
        FieldWidget
          TimeRangeWidget.php
  time_range.info.yml
  time_range.module
```

**time_range.info.yml**:

```
name: 'Time Range'
type: module
description: 'Provides the ability to store start and end times.'
package: Custom
version: '8.0.0'
core: 8.x
project: 'drupal'
dependencies:
  - datetime
  - datetime_range
```

**time_range.module**:

```
<?php

function time_range_field_widget_info() {
  return array(
    'daterange_time_only' => array(
      'label' => t('Time Range'),
      'field types' => array('datetime_range'),
      'settings' => array(
        'add_new_text' => 'Add new customer...', //Don't know which setting this is suppose to be
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

**TimeRangeWidget.php**:

```
namespace Drupal\time_range\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget; 

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Drupal\datetime_range\Plugin\Field\FieldType\DateRangeItem;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'daterange_time_only' widget.
 *
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "daterange_time_only",
 *   label = @Translation("Time range"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "daterange"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class TimeRangeWidget extends DateRangeWidgetBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * The date format storage.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface
   */
  protected $dateStorage;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function __construct($plugin_id, $plugin_definition, FieldDefinitionInterface $field_definition, array $settings, array $third_party_settings, EntityStorageInterface $date_storage) {
    parent::__construct($plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $field_definition, $settings, $third_party_settings);

    $this->dateStorage = $date_storage;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $configuration['field_definition'],
      $configuration['settings'],
      $configuration['third_party_settings'],
      $container->get('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('date_format')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $element = parent::formElement($items, $delta, $element, $form, $form_state);

    // Identify the type of date and time elements to use.
//    switch ($this->getFieldSetting('datetime_type')) {
//      case DateRangeItem::DATETIME_TYPE_DATE:
//      case DateRangeItem::DATETIME_TYPE_ALLDAY:
//        $date_type = 'date';
//        $time_type = 'none';
//        $date_format = $this->dateStorage->load('html_date')->getPattern();
//        $time_format = '';
//        break;
//
//      default:
//        $date_type = 'date';
//        $time_type = 'time';
//        $date_format = $this->dateStorage->load('html_date')->getPattern();
//        $time_format = $this->dateStorage->load('html_time')->getPattern();
//        break;
//    }

    $element['value'] += [
      '#date_date_format' => $date_format,
      '#date_date_element' => 'none',
      '#date_date_callbacks' => [],
      '#date_time_format' => $time_format,
      '#date_time_element' => $time_type,
      '#date_time_callbacks' => [],
    ];

    $element['end_value'] += [
      '#date_date_format' => $date_format,
      '#date_date_element' => 'none',
      '#date_date_callbacks' => [],
      '#date_time_format' => $time_format,
      '#date_time_element' => $time_type,
      '#date_time_callbacks' => [],
    ];

    return $element;
  }

}
```

However, the widget doesn't show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update: [Time Range Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/time_range) <sup><sub><sub>on drupal.org</sub></sub></sup>

(Old) [Github here](https://github.com/Chris-Happy7/d8-time-range/tree/time_range), with basic installation instruction in the README.md file.

My current structure of my custom module time_range is this:

```
time_range
  src
    Plugin
      Field
        FieldWidget
          DateRangeWidgetBase.php
          TimeRangeWidget.php
          TimeRangeWidgetBase.php
  time_range.info.yml
  time_range.module
```

**time_range.info.yml**:

```
name: 'Time Range'
type: module
description: 'Provides the ability to store start and end times.'
package: Custom
version: '8.0.0'
core: 8.x
project: 'drupal'
dependencies:
  - datetime
  - datetime_range
```

**time_range.module**:

```
<?php

function time_range_field_widget_info() {
  return array(
    'daterange_time_only' => array(
      'label' => t('Time Range'),
      'field types' => array('datetime_range'),
      'settings' => array(
        'add_new_text' => 'Add new customer...',
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

**DateRangeWidgetBase.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\datetime_range\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget;

use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\datetime\Plugin\Field\FieldType\DateTimeItem;
use Drupal\datetime\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\DateTimeWidgetBase;
use Drupal\datetime_range\Plugin\Field\FieldType\DateRangeItem;

/**
 * Base class for the 'daterange_*' widgets.
 */
class DateRangeWidgetBase extends DateTimeWidgetBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $element = parent::formElement($items, $delta, $element, $form, $form_state);
    $element['#element_validate'][] = [$this, 'validateStartEnd'];
    $element['value']['#title'] = $this->t('Start');

    $element['end_value'] = [
      '#title' => $this->t('End'),
    ] + $element['value'];

    if ($items[$delta]->start_date) {
      /** @var \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime $start_date */
      $start_date = $items[$delta]->start_date;
      $element['value']['#default_value'] = $this->createDefaultValue($start_date, $element['value']['#date_timezone']);
    }

    if ($items[$delta]->end_date) {
      /** @var \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime $end_date */
      $end_date = $items[$delta]->end_date;
      $element['end_value']['#default_value'] = $this->createDefaultValue($end_date, $element['end_value']['#date_timezone']);
    }

    return $element;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function massageFormValues(array $values, array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // The widget form element type has transformed the value to a
    // DrupalDateTime object at this point. We need to convert it back to the
    // storage timezone and format.
    foreach ($values as &$item) {
      if (!empty($item['value']) && $item['value'] instanceof DrupalDateTime) {
        /** @var \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime $start_date */
        $start_date = $item['value'];
        switch ($this->getFieldSetting('datetime_type')) {
          case DateRangeItem::DATETIME_TYPE_DATE:
            // If this is a date-only field, set it to the default time so the
            // timezone conversion can be reversed.
            datetime_date_default_time($start_date);
            $format = DATETIME_DATE_STORAGE_FORMAT;
            break;

          case DateRangeItem::DATETIME_TYPE_ALLDAY:
            // All day fields start at midnight on the starting date, but are
            // stored like datetime fields, so we need to adjust the time.
            // This function is called twice, so to prevent a double conversion
            // we need to explicitly set the timezone.
            $start_date->setTimeZone(timezone_open(drupal_get_user_timezone()));
            $start_date->setTime(0, 0, 0);
            $format = DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT;
            break;

          default:
            $format = DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT;
            break;
        }
        // Adjust the date for storage.
        $start_date->setTimezone(new \DateTimezone(DATETIME_STORAGE_TIMEZONE));
        $item['value'] = $start_date->format($format);
      }

      if (!empty($item['end_value']) && $item['end_value'] instanceof DrupalDateTime) {
        /** @var \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime $end_date */
        $end_date = $item['end_value'];
        switch ($this->getFieldSetting('datetime_type')) {
          case DateRangeItem::DATETIME_TYPE_DATE:
            // If this is a date-only field, set it to the default time so the
            // timezone conversion can be reversed.
            datetime_date_default_time($end_date);
            $format = DATETIME_DATE_STORAGE_FORMAT;
            break;

          case DateRangeItem::DATETIME_TYPE_ALLDAY:
            // All day fields end at midnight on the end date, but are
            // stored like datetime fields, so we need to adjust the time.
            // This function is called twice, so to prevent a double conversion
            // we need to explicitly set the timezone.
            $end_date->setTimeZone(timezone_open(drupal_get_user_timezone()));
            $end_date->setTime(23, 59, 59);
            $format = DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT;
            break;

          default:
            $format = DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT;
            break;
        }
        // Adjust the date for storage.
        $end_date->setTimezone(new \DateTimezone(DATETIME_STORAGE_TIMEZONE));
        $item['end_value'] = $end_date->format($format);
      }
    }

    return $values;
  }

  /**
   * #element_validate callback to ensure that the start date <= the end date.
   *
   * @param array $element
   *   An associative array containing the properties and children of the
   *   generic form element.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *   The current state of the form.
   * @param array $complete_form
   *   The complete form structure.
   */
  public function validateStartEnd(array &$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
    $start_date = $element['value']['#value']['object'];
    $end_date = $element['end_value']['#value']['object'];

    if ($start_date instanceof DrupalDateTime && $end_date instanceof DrupalDateTime) {
      if ($start_date->format('U') !== $end_date->format('U')) {
        $interval = $start_date->diff($end_date);
        if ($interval->invert === 1) {
          $form_state->setError($element, $this->t('The @title end date cannot be before the start date', ['@title' => $element['#title']]));
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Creates a date object for use as a default value.
   *
   * This will take a default value, apply the proper timezone for display in
   * a widget, and set the default time for date-only fields.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime $date
   *   The UTC default date.
   * @param string $timezone
   *   The timezone to apply.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime
   *   A date object for use as a default value in a field widget.
   */
  protected function createDefaultValue($date, $timezone) {
    // The date was created and verified during field_load(), so it is safe to
    // use without further inspection.
    if ($this->getFieldSetting('datetime_type') == DateTimeItem::DATETIME_TYPE_DATE) {
      // A date without time will pick up the current time, use the default
      // time.
      datetime_date_default_time($date);
    }
    $date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone($timezone));
    return $date;
  }

}
```

**TimeRangeWidget.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\time_range\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Drupal\datetime_range\Plugin\Field\FieldType\DateRangeItem;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'daterange_time_only' widget.
 *
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "daterange_time_only",
 *   label = @Translation("Time range"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "daterange"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class TimeRangeWidget extends TimeRangeWidgetBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * The date format storage.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface
   */
  protected $dateStorage;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function __construct($plugin_id, $plugin_definition, FieldDefinitionInterface $field_definition, array $settings, array $third_party_settings, EntityStorageInterface $date_storage) {
    parent::__construct($plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $field_definition, $settings, $third_party_settings);

    $this->dateStorage = $date_storage;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $configuration['field_definition'],
      $configuration['settings'],
      $configuration['third_party_settings'],
      $container->get('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('date_format')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $element = parent::formElement($items, $delta, $element, $form, $form_state);

    // Identify the type of date and time elements to use.
    switch ($this->getFieldSetting('datetime_type')) {
      case DateRangeItem::DATETIME_TYPE_DATE:
      case DateRangeItem::DATETIME_TYPE_ALLDAY:
        $date_type = 'date';
        $time_type = 'none';
        $date_format = $this->dateStorage->load('html_date')->getPattern();
        $time_format = '';
        break;

      default:
        $date_type = 'date';
        $time_type = 'time';
        $date_format = $this->dateStorage->load('html_date')->getPattern();
        $time_format = $this->dateStorage->load('html_time')->getPattern();
        break;
    }

    $element['value'] += [
      '#date_date_format' => $date_format,
      '#date_date_element' => 'none',
      '#date_date_callbacks' => [],
      '#date_time_format' => $time_format,
      '#date_time_element' => $time_type,
      '#date_time_callbacks' => [],
    ];

    $element['end_value'] += [
      '#date_date_format' => $date_format,
      '#date_date_element' => 'none',
      '#date_date_callbacks' => [],
      '#date_time_format' => $time_format,
      '#date_time_element' => $time_type,
      '#date_time_callbacks' => [],
    ];

    return $element;
  }

}
```

**TimeRangeWidgetBase.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\time_range\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget;

use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\datetime\Plugin\Field\FieldType\DateTimeItem;
use Drupal\datetime\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\DateTimeWidgetBase;
use Drupal\datetime_range\Plugin\Field\FieldType\DateRangeItem;

/**
 * Base class for the 'daterange_*' widgets.
 */
class TimeRangeWidgetBase extends DateTimeWidgetBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $element = parent::formElement($items, $delta, $element, $form, $form_state);
    $element['#element_validate'][] = [$this, 'validateStartEnd'];
    $element['value']['#title'] = $this->t('Start');

    $element['end_value'] = [
      '#title' => $this->t('End'),
    ] + $element['value'];

    if ($items[$delta]->start_date) {
      /** @var \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime $start_date */
      $start_date = $items[$delta]->start_date;
      $element['value']['#default_value'] = $this->createDefaultValue($start_date, $element['value']['#date_timezone']);
    }

    if ($items[$delta]->end_date) {
      /** @var \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime $end_date */
      $end_date = $items[$delta]->end_date;
      $element['end_value']['#default_value'] = $this->createDefaultValue($end_date, $element['end_value']['#date_timezone']);
    }

    return $element;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function massageFormValues(array $values, array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // The widget form element type has transformed the value to a
    // DrupalDateTime object at this point. We need to convert it back to the
    // storage timezone and format.
    foreach ($values as &$item) {
      if (!empty($item['value']) && $item['value'] instanceof DrupalDateTime) {
        /** @var \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime $start_date */
        $start_date = $item['value'];
        switch ($this->getFieldSetting('datetime_type')) {
          case DateRangeItem::DATETIME_TYPE_DATE:
            // If this is a date-only field, set it to the default time so the
            // timezone conversion can be reversed.
            datetime_date_default_time($start_date);
            $format = DATETIME_DATE_STORAGE_FORMAT;
            break;

          case DateRangeItem::DATETIME_TYPE_ALLDAY:
            // All day fields start at midnight on the starting date, but are
            // stored like datetime fields, so we need to adjust the time.
            // This function is called twice, so to prevent a double conversion
            // we need to explicitly set the timezone.
            $start_date->setTimeZone(timezone_open(drupal_get_user_timezone()));
            $start_date->setTime(0, 0, 0);
            $format = DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT;
            break;

          default:
            $format = DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT;
            break;
        }
        // Adjust the date for storage.
        $start_date->setTimezone(new \DateTimezone(DATETIME_STORAGE_TIMEZONE));
        $item['value'] = $start_date->format($format);
      }

      if (!empty($item['end_value']) && $item['end_value'] instanceof DrupalDateTime) {
        /** @var \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime $end_date */
        $end_date = $item['end_value'];
        switch ($this->getFieldSetting('datetime_type')) {
          case DateRangeItem::DATETIME_TYPE_DATE:
            // If this is a date-only field, set it to the default time so the
            // timezone conversion can be reversed.
            datetime_date_default_time($end_date);
            $format = DATETIME_DATE_STORAGE_FORMAT;
            break;

          case DateRangeItem::DATETIME_TYPE_ALLDAY:
            // All day fields end at midnight on the end date, but are
            // stored like datetime fields, so we need to adjust the time.
            // This function is called twice, so to prevent a double conversion
            // we need to explicitly set the timezone.
            $end_date->setTimeZone(timezone_open(drupal_get_user_timezone()));
            $end_date->setTime(23, 59, 59);
            $format = DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT;
            break;

          default:
            $format = DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT;
            break;
        }
        // Adjust the date for storage.
        $end_date->setTimezone(new \DateTimezone(DATETIME_STORAGE_TIMEZONE));
        $item['end_value'] = $end_date->format($format);
      }
    }

    return $values;
  }

  /**
   * #element_validate callback to ensure that the start date <= the end date.
   *
   * @param array $element
   *   An associative array containing the properties and children of the
   *   generic form element.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *   The current state of the form.
   * @param array $complete_form
   *   The complete form structure.
   */
  public function validateStartEnd(array &$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
    $start_date = $element['value']['#value']['object'];
    $end_date = $element['end_value']['#value']['object'];

    if ($start_date instanceof DrupalDateTime && $end_date instanceof DrupalDateTime) {
      if ($start_date->format('U') !== $end_date->format('U')) {
        $interval = $start_date->diff($end_date);
        if ($interval->invert === 1) {
          $form_state->setError($element, $this->t('The @title end date cannot be before the start date', ['@title' => $element['#title']]));
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Creates a date object for use as a default value.
   *
   * This will take a default value, apply the proper timezone for display in
   * a widget, and set the default time for date-only fields.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime $date
   *   The UTC default date.
   * @param string $timezone
   *   The timezone to apply.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime
   *   A date object for use as a default value in a field widget.
   */
  protected function createDefaultValue($date, $timezone) {
    // The date was created and verified during field_load(), so it is safe to
    // use without further inspection.
    if ($this->getFieldSetting('datetime_type') == DateTimeItem::DATETIME_TYPE_DATE) {
      // A date without time will pick up the current time, use the default
      // time.
      datetime_date_default_time($date);
    }
    $date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone($timezone));
    return $date;
  }

}
```

Now I just gotta find a how to remove the seconds from the field...

Note:

- You need to install Date Range
- Flush the Cache
- Enable the module
- Select Time Range in the Form display settings, not the field settings.

Comment: As of Drupal 8.3.3 I see a Datetime Range module in Core, marked experimental.

Comment: Yes, but this is a time range field :)

Comment: Nice! Why don't you create a module (or at least a sandbox) on drupal.org?

Comment: @user1527576 Offical module here: https://www.drupal.org/project/time_range