# Make date/time range end value optional

Tags: 8, entities, datetime

After two days of researching and experiment, I was finally able to make a time range field [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/227029/create-a-time-range-field/227032#227032).

However, now my client wants the end value to be optional. I saw this [article](https://www.drupal.org/node/2794481#comment-11817298) that uses a `field type` to make the value optional, but I would prefer to just use my widget. Would this be possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Not currently possible with the standard field. There is an issue to potentially add this feature once some more pressing issues get ironed out.